# How to snap elements to grid by jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are some elements that have `class='snap'`

I want to find these elements in the body. Then `snap` and `resize` elements to fit grids by `Jquery`.

**`When?`**

- The document is ready.
- The window is resized.

**`Note:`**

- Size of grid cells are `10px`
- Contents of elements can be different.
- Element can move down maximum in 1 cell size. (Up is not allowed).
- Because of responsive elements, It's not true to snap the element by specifying width and height.

[**See on JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/rV27G/4/)

[image]

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

**JsFiddle updated:** Removed width of `.content` in `CSS`, It can be `not specified`.

Comment: Have you actually thought about how to code that bit? Or even found a solution on SO or Google?

Comment: Position the nodes by percentage/what you like, get their position _x, y_, mod these numbers by grid cell length to get _a, b_, and set their position in pixels to _x - a, y - b_

Comment: @putvande I tried to set a margin or increase the height but not successful. I did not add these codes to the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, and this is just an idea that is perfectible, is getting the `offset` of the `.snap` div and remove all margins. Then you snap to the next (right and bellow) lines :

```
var Content = {
    snapElement: function(element){
        offset = element.offset();
        element.css('left', (Math.ceil(offset.left/10)*10)+'px');
        element.css('top', (Math.ceil(offset.top/10)*10)+'px');
        element.css('margin', '0');
    },
    snapElements: function(){
        var elements = $("body").find(".snap");
        elements.each(function(){
            Content.snapElement($(this));
        });     
    }
}
```

You will also have to make your `.snap` divs relative :

```
.snap {position:relative;}
```

**[The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rV27G/1/)**

You can also keep the margins but you will have to subtract them to the `left` and `top`.

**Edit :** A more sophisticated **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rV27G/5/)** that handle `width`

Comment: Good, But remove `.content` width and try to resize the window to see the problem.

Comment: Funny one... It was because of the `+1` and `-1`. I edited my answer with a newest link to the last demo. I just changed `diffHeight = (Math.ceil(height/10)*10) - height;` to `diffHeight = (Math.ceil((height - 1)/10)*10) - height;`

Comment: Because of responsive elements, It's not true to specify `width` and `height` to the element. So your first `demo` is near to correct solution but not in resizing window without specified with of `.content`

Comment: Well, you are surely better placed to know what you really want to do than I am. I just hope that this answer is enough to guide you in the right way, or at least that it gives you a few tricks.